# Adding key value pairs to redux store

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I am trying to use redux to add key value pairs to my store. However, Im not sure how to accomplish this. In short, i am retrieving data from firebase, I want to add that data to my redux store, but I have to do it one item at a time. My desired structure of my state object is something like this:

```
reminders
 - reminder key 1
   - reminder title
   - reminder date 1
 - reminder key 2
   - reminder title
   - reminder date 1
```

and so on.

But I cant figure out how to add children to my state.reminders object

Here is my action:

```
const fetchReminders = (uid) => async dispatch => {
    firebaseReminders.child(uid).orderByChild("date").on("value", snapshot => {

      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.val())
        dispatch({
          type: 'fetchReminders',
          value: child.val(),
          key: child.key
        });
      })

    });
};
```

so this would dispatch the action for every single item that I retrieve from the database, and then in my reducer I want to add that item to the state tree using action.key as the key. Currently I have

```
const remindersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

        case "fetchReminders":
             return Object.assign({}, state, {
                reminders: action.value
             });


        default: return state;
    }

};
```

which is not correct. How can I add a child node to my state.reminders object with the key of action.key, and the value of action.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let initialState = {
  reminders: {}
}

const remindersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "fetchReminders":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        reminders: {
          ...state.reminders,
          [action.key]: action.value
        }
      });
    default: return state;
  }
};

let state1 = remindersReducer(initialState, {
    type: 'fetchReminders',
    key: 'reminderKey1',
    value: 'reminderValue1'
});
console.log(state1)

let state2 = remindersReducer(state1, {
    type: 'fetchReminders',
    key: 'reminderKey2',
    value: 'reminderValue2'
});
console.log(state2)

let state3 = remindersReducer(state2, {
    type: 'fetchReminders',
    key: 'reminderKey3',
    value: 'reminderValue3'
});
console.log(state3)
```

The snippet should help you achieve what you want to do.
You can assign an object as the key of action.key by using the following format:

```
{
  [action.key]: action.value
}
```

Its called Computed Property Names.

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
>   supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
>   in brackets [], that will be computed and used as the property name.
>   [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)